# What would cause just one photo from my phone camera to have large, blotchy magenta areas?

Tags: lighting, image-quality, artifacts

[image]

What would cause the pink on this picture? All the pics before and after were normal. No filter, no flash.[image][image]

Comment: What type of light was your light source?

Comment: Natural.... There's a bay window about 5 feet in front of him

Comment: You're saying there was no artificial light source? Does the  camera have an LED flash (like many phone cameras do)?

Comment: What photo app were you using?  Are you sure a filter couldn't have been applied accidentally?  And why are you showing a screenshot of a photo instead of the photo itself?  Could the effect be caused by the viewer you're using?

Comment: I took the picture with my phone. The flash wasn't on,no photo app,No filter. I took several pictures ones before and after all look normal.  I took screan shot because said original pic was too big. Also my phone camera is very basic.

Comment: *screen shot.  And yes only natural light, It was gloomy out also.

Comment: Can you post the images directly before and after in the sequence?

Comment: Also, it would be ideal if you can rescale the image down and upload that instead of a screenshot -- there should be apps for that.

Comment: I don't know how to resale the image... The second pic is before and third is after... I snapped the pics one after another. Camera phone very basic. The phone doesn't even have a notification light . Its an LG xcharge

Comment: Could this be some kind of strong near-IR illuminator (security camera, remote control, someone elses camera using AF assist....)?

Comment: No, was only in front of a window. Tv was off and remote not near also no security camerad, it was a gloomy day... Could it have been caused by that? I heard that can create purple fringe. Could this be purple fringe?

Comment: Looks like a software issue, maybe multiframe fusion gone wrong because of the strong motion. A lot of phones are doing multiframe HDR by default, without necessarily telling the user about it.

Comment: I just looked at phone setting and it does have HDR set as auto , your answer is prob most likely.... Thank you so much

Comment: @Dsilveira85 Great! I'm turning my comment into an answer (my first on this site), maybe you can click accept on it?

Comment: Thank you so much Tomi

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a software issue, maybe multiframe fusion gone wrong because of the strong motion. A lot of phones are doing multiframe HDR by default, without necessarily telling the user about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your phone erroneously applied some kind of filter...Do you have filters available on your phone that look like that?

Comment: No its a really basic phone. I don't do filters eaither,plus the pics before and after are reg...They are posted above. Thank you though. I'm trying to figure it out :/ the closest thing I found is purple fringe, do you think it could be?